# How to count times of appearance of a certain word in a div full of text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to create an event function that's associated with a button that, when clicked after you input a phrase into the text area, counts how many times this phrase has appeared in the text (only the p elements) and simultaneously output the value (how many times) into a span element that this function creates.

The intended result is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXKBB.png)

This is my html:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
<p>The Phoenix Suns are a professional basketball team based in Phoenix, 
    Arizona. They are members of the ...</p>
<p>The Suns have been generally successful since they began play as an
 expansion team in 1968. In forty years of play they have posted ...</p>
<p>On January 22, 1968, the NBA awarded expansion franchises to an ownership 
group from Phoenix and one from Milwaukee. ...</p>
<ul>
    <li>Richard L. Bloch, investment broker/real estate developer...</li> 
    <li>Karl Eller, outdoor advertising company owner and former...</li>
    <li>Donald Pitt, Tucson-based attorney;</li>
    <li>Don Diamond, Tucson-based real estate investor.</li>
</ul>
</div>

<p>
Page by Marty Stepp. <br />
Some (all) information taken from Wikipedia.
</p>
<hr />

<div>
Search for text:
<input id="searchtext" type="text"  /> 
<button id="searchbutton">Search</button>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is my js function:

```
function count_search(event){
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.setAttribute("id", "output");
document.body.appendChild(span);
var searchPhrase = document.querySelector("#searchtext").value;
var main = document.querySelector("#main");
var mainParas = main.querySelectorAll(" p ").textContent;
document.getElementById("#output").innerHTML = 
          (mainParas.match(/searchPhrase/g)).length;
/*var times = (mainParas.match(/searchPhrase/g) || []).length;
var content = "Searched for the word '" + searchPhrase + "' for " + times + " 
times. "; 
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = content; */
}
```

However, the result just won't show. Can you please help me? Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: can you post your code in the text and not as an image so it can be edited/copied more easily

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I hope it is easier now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<body>
<div id="main">
<p>The Phoenix Suns are a professional basketball team based in Phoenix, 
    Arizona. They are members of the ...</p>
<p>The Suns have been generally successful since they began play as an
 expansion team in 1968. In forty years of play they have posted ...</p>
<p>On January 22, 1968, the NBA awarded expansion franchises to an ownership 
group from Phoenix and one from Milwaukee. ...</p>
<ul>
    <li>Richard L. Bloch, investment broker/real estate developer...</li> 
    <li>Karl Eller, outdoor advertising company owner and former...</li>
    <li>Donald Pitt, Tucson-based attorney;</li>
    <li>Don Diamond, Tucson-based real estate investor.</li>
</ul>
</div>

<p>
Page by Marty Stepp. <br />
Some (all) information taken from Wikipedia.
</p>
<hr />

<div>
Search for text:
<input id="searchtext" type="text"  /> 
<button id="searchbutton" onClick="count_search()">Search</button>
</div>
<script>
  function count_search(event){
      span = document.createElement('span');
      span.setAttribute("id", "output");
      document.body.appendChild(span);
      
      var searchPhrase = document.querySelector("#searchtext").value;
      searchPhrase = new RegExp(searchPhrase, 'g');
      var main = document.querySelector("#main");
      let count = 0;
      var mainParas = main.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(ele => {
       
        const times = ele.innerHTML.match(searchPhrase);
        count += times ? times.length : 0;
      });
      span.innerHTML = count;
      
  }
</script>
</body>
```

So the reason it was not showing up before is cause there was no onclick event associated with the button. The following code should help in a way.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you. It takes all child elements of type `p` of the main div, takes their contents and concatenates them into a single string.
Then it searches this string for the word entered into the input field and returns the number of ocurrences.

Word search is done using a regular expression with two modifiers: `g` to let the search continue after the first match and `i` to ignore capitalization.

Notice how it returns 2 when you enter 'dolor', because the third ocurrence of dolor is in a `li`element, not a `p`.

```js
function search() {
    // Get the word to count
    var searchString = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var textDiv = document.getElementById("main");
    // Get all p elements in the main div
    var childNodes = textDiv.getElementsByTagName('p')
    // Store all text from the child elements in a single string
    var completetext = ""
    for(var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        completetext = completetext + childNodes[i].innerHTML
    }
    // Search the string and count the ocurrences
    var regEx = new RegExp(searchString, "gi");
    // When match() returns 0, replace it with an empty array
    // to make the length work in this case
    var count = (completetext.match(regEx) || []).length
    result.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum</p>
    <li>dolor sit amet.</li>
</div>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button" onclick="search()">Search</button>
<span id="result">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on the right way. Once you have all the `p`'s in the main div you can iterate over them in order to get its text. Then you could append to a string that contains all the texts so you could search in it after. For that, create a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with the value you want to search, finally use [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to find out the times the string is in the text.

```js
function count_search() {
  var allText = "";

  var element = document.getElementById("output");
  element && element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.setAttribute("id", "output");
  document.body.appendChild(span);

  var searchPhrase = document.querySelector("#searchtext").value;

  var mainParas = document.querySelectorAll("#main > p");

  mainParas.forEach(el => allText+= el.innerText);

  var regex = new RegExp(searchPhrase, "gi");
  var times = allText.match(regex);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = times ? `How many times I searched for the word "${searchPhrase}": ${times.length}` : "No matches found";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p>The Phoenix Suns are a professional basketball team based in Phoenix, 
        Arizona. They are members of the ...</p>
    <p>The Suns have been generally successful since they began play as an
    expansion team in 1968. In forty years of play they have posted ...</p>
    <p>On January 22, 1968, the NBA awarded expansion franchises to an ownership 
    group from Phoenix and one from Milwaukee. ...</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Richard L. Bloch, investment broker/real estate developer...</li> 
      <li>Karl Eller, outdoor advertising company owner and former...</li>
      <li>Donald Pitt, Tucson-based attorney;</li>
      <li>Don Diamond, Tucson-based real estate investor.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>
    Page by Marty Stepp. <br />
    Some (all) information taken from Wikipedia.
  </p>
  <hr />
  <div>
    Search for text:
    <input id="searchtext" type="text"  /> 
    <button id="searchbutton" onclick="count_search()">Search</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some JS that does this

```
function count_search(event){
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.setAttribute("id", "output");
  document.body.appendChild(span);
  var searchPhrase = document.querySelector("#searchtext").value;
  var main = document.querySelector("#main");
  var mainParas = main.querySelectorAll("p");
  mainParas = Array.from(mainParas)
  for (let i = 0; i<mainParas.length;i++) {
    mainParas[i] = mainParas[i].textContent
  }
  mainParas = mainParas.join(' ')
  words = mainParas.split(' ')
  count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i<words.length;i++) {
    if (words[i] == searchPhrase) {
      count++
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = count
}
```

Comment: You don't need a loop to combine the text of the paragraphs, simply using main.innerText will contain the text of all it's childNodes